# Download large xls files using servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am fetching large data's from DB ( around 50,000 rows) and converted into XL file using POI jar then I pass the file to client side but i am getting "connection timed out" message from my browser. Is this possible to send the excel row by row ( like streaming ).

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options related to it, please take a look at following links: [BigGridDemo](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/BigGridDemo.java.html) and [usage example](http://web.archive.org/web/20110821054135/http://www.realdevelopers.com/blog/code/excel).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this file we written large file into disk. But i just want to streaming the data row by row while generating the XL. Please let me know, if you know anything similar like this.